# Make OpenGL application run in Windows without OpenGL set up

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2013

**Aim**

- To run my OpenGL application in a computer with no OpenGL set up.

**Process**

- I start a new Win32 Console Application with Visual Studio 2013
- Using C++
- GLUT and OpenGL libraries are linked to my project
- Display mode : GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE
- Can build without error and it runs as expected in my computer
- Copy just the Project\Release\Project.exe and glut32.dll to other computers with no OpenGL set up neither Visual Studio installed.
- In some computers my application runs perfectly.
- In the others my application runs with black screen displayed in the OpenGL window which is expected to display graphics.
- The command-line interface and the OpenGL window are both active. There are keyboard events in my application by introducing the function glutKeyboardFunc(). When I press a specific key there is an update shown in the command-line interface so I know the command-line interface and the OpenGL window are active. The latter just does not display anything but black.

**Look For**

- Answers for why my application displays differently from computer to computer
- Solutions for this

Please bear with my English and stupidity...

Comment: We need more info.  What sort of computers isn't it working on?  What ones does it work on?  Look for commonality among those groups.  It could be the computers it doesn't work on need updated video drivers to support the version of OpenGL you're trying to use.

Comment: Are you testing GL return results from all of the functions that you call?  Which version of OpenGL are you using?  2.0?  3.3?  4.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved... Thanks guys

I used gluPerspetive() and gluLookAt() in my application.

On some computers they do not have glu.dll, so the glu functions in my application are not available on them, resulting in nothing displayed.

Simply I send glu.dll and glu.lib together with my .exe and it works...

Comment: glu is actually _part_ of the windows API (like OpenGL 1.1). As a result, the `glu32.dll` did ship with every (desktop) windows version since windows 95. Since you said `glu.dll` and not `glu32.dll`, you might have not linked against the correct library. However, the application should fail to start if the required libraries cannot be found. It is totally unlcear what is really happening in your case, but the explanation given in this answer sounds dubious to me. Deploying the `.lib` file along with the executable is totally useless too, btw.